# Draw a circle on bitmap

Tags: android, android-canvas

I have searched for many answers here for drawing a circle on bitmap using canvas. However, I got some error in the code and the application stopped without any exception.

Can anyone give me some help? It works fine with I create a blank bitmap and draw a circle on it.
Any help will be appreciated!

```
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.main);

Paint paint = new Paint();
//paint.setAntiAlias(true);
paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);

Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmp);
canvas.drawCircle(50, 50, 10, paint);

ImageView imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
//imageView.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
imageView.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```

Comment: can we have logcat pls

Comment: logcat has so many information..can u tell what is relevant infomation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read somewhere that Resource bitmaps are immutable. Try...

```
bmp = bmp.copy(bmp.getConfig(), true);
```

Comment: Glad it worked:)
Well if the variable is immutable, you can't change it after construction. So when you make a copy (and use that instead) you can.

Answer (score 0):

This will draw a circle for you for given height

```
 private RectF outerCircle;
    diameter =400;

   int left = (width - diameter) / 2;
   int top = (height - diameter) / 2;
   int bottom = top + diameter;
   int right = left + diameter;
    outerCircle = new RectF(left, top, right, bottom);
```